# How to properly provide license when packaging?

Tags: packaging, license

I wrote  a BTRSF GUI for Ubuntu and  I want to license it with the MIT License.Now that I'm packaging it in a .deb format how and were should I include a copy of the license?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your licenses in [`debian/copyright`](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/debian-dir-overview.html#the-copyright-file) (in your build source). This should be automatically transposed into `/usr/share/doc/PACKAGE/copyright` during the packaging process.